# How to pass a password to Runtime.exec

Tags: java, console, passwords

I want to download svn data, unfortunately it is on an svn+ssh url, so I have to enter the password always. To get all versions with one program call, I want to skip the password entering. For this, I need to enter the password to the skript, so at least I can't do this with a simple shell skript, so I tried Java. The method I actuall wrote looks like this:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException,
        IOException {
    String user = args[0];
    String passwd = args[1];

    String url = args[2];

    String command = "svn checkout svn+ssh://" + user + "@" + url;

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    System.out.println("Start");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            p.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
    BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( p.getErrorStream ()));
    String line = "";
    System.out.println("Waiting...");
    while ( line!=null)
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        if ( inp.ready())
        {
            line = inp.readLine();
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
        }
        if ( stderr.ready())
        {
            line = stderr.readLine();
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
        }
    }
    out.write(passwd + '\n');
    out.write(passwd + '\n');
    p.waitFor();
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I don't even get the Password-Enter-Thing in the output, it is only written on the console. Does anyone know how to pass the password?

I always searched for this, but the answers where "Read the stout as well (I am reading it already) or give svn the password via --password, which does not work in my case. Has anybody an idea how to solve this?

Best Regards
DaGeRe

Comment: You can't set up public key authentication for SSH?

Comment: In what sense does `--password` not work?

Answer (score 0):

The `svn` command is opening the connection to the console directly to be sure that it is talking to the real user.  It does this to protect the user in the case that he / she has been tricked into running the command via some sneaky password grabber.  The Java `Process` stuff can't override this mechanism because it happens directly between the `svn` command and the operating system.

I think you should either persevere with `--password` (*how / why is it not working for you??*), or switch to using public key authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I can login via SSH (so I can use ssh username@server without beeing asked for a password), but for svn, I have to enter the password twice, I don't know why. --password isn't working in the sense that it just does not log me in or change anything - if I'm using --password, I also have to enter the password. My workaround now was not very nice, but worked: I enter everything via java.awt.robot, so it is just as if the user would enter something. It is maybe a little bit more work, but it does what it should...